# Infinite Loop while creating list of lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble creating a list of lists that contains all possible work schedules. A simple example is:

Work day shift... next day work day, night or be off: [day, [day, night, off]]

Work night shift, next day be off:
[night, off]

If off, next day you can work day, night or be off:
[off, [day, night, off]

For 3 days the list of lists can look like:

[day, [[day, [day, night, off]], [night, [off]], [off, [day, night, off]]]

I was able to create a schedule for next day:

```
def schedule(i):
    Tree = [0]*3
    Tree[0] = i

    for x in range(len(Tree)-1):
        if Tree[x] == "day":
            Tree[x+1] = "[day, night, off]"
        elif Tree[x] == "night":
            Tree[x+1] = "off"
        else:
            Tree[x+1] = "[day, night, off]"


print(Tree)

schedule('day')
```

However, when I try to recurrsively create a list of list to extend the schedule out for a week or so, I get error massages and infinite loops. Here is one example:

```
def RecSched(i, count):
    RecSched = [0]*7
    RecSched[0] = i
    while count > 0:
        for x in range(len(RecSched)-1):
            if RecSched[x] == "day":
                RecSched[x+1] = "[day, night, off]"
            elif RecSched[x] == "night":
                RecSched[x+1] = "off"
            else:
                RecSched[x+1] = "[day, night, off]"

    count = count - 1
    RecSched(x+1, count)

RecSched('day', 7)
```

I'm new and learning. Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong and what is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in the question so we know that's not part of the problem.

Comment: Incidentally this is a situation where pdb is very handy for debugging as you can step over the problem one line at a time. Which in this case will show you that indentation is causing your problem.

Comment: Those are not nested lists. They are strings in a list.